# Apache solr wild card searching with multiple words

Tags: solr

We are using apache solr with php.

There is a problem in wild card searching.

We want to search "project manage*" which can list possible results like project manager, project management etc. However, it is not working whenever there are two words in wild card searching

For example "projectmanage*" is working whereas "proejct manage*" is not working. We also tried by escaping the space but it is not working either..

Looking forward to all valuable inputs.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When applying a wild card, the regular analysis chain is not performed when querying. This results in Solr looking for tokens starting with with "project manage" - and if you have an analysis chain when indexing, your text is usually split into multiple tokens.

You can [use a Shingle filter to index multiple tokens](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) as a single token, which can be used to get around the issue (be sure to use the same separator as you use in your text).

Another option is to lowercase the field when indexing and querying and use a regular StrField which isn't processed in any way, or use a KeywordTokenizer - which keeps the indexed content as a single token.